# SMS sent ContentObserver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider

I'm writing an app that sends sms (with SmsManager), and I want to know if a message was sent successfully or not. I'm going to use a ContentObserver with `content://sms/sent`, but may not be a good idea because I want to handle only the messages sent by my app.

Any suggestion?