# How to store data received through an SMS in an Android application's database?

Tags: android

How to store data through SMS sending/receiving application in my database?

If it is possible then I would appreciate it if someone could illustrate how with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it possible.
You should use broadcast receiver for geting sending and receiving event of sms.

onRecive method you should write your code.

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
  <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>        

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission> 


// SMSReceiver.java
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{ 
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        Log.i(TAG, "SMS received.");
        ....
    }
}
```

or you can also read these tutorial for more help
[React on incoming SMS](http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html)

Comment: Thanks...but,I want to get this received message in database directly.so,I would appreciate if you explain it with example.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to save a SMS when the SMS is received, it's a duplicate of [Android SMS broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)
- If you want to save a SMS when it is sent, it's a duplicate of [SMS sent ContentObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332771/sms-sent-contentobserver)
- If you want to read existing stored SMS (received or send), it's a duplicate of [How to use SMS content provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976252/how-to-use-sms-content-provider-where-are-the-docs)